# m3u8 Blank screen for video but the audio is playing

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller, m3u8

I am streaming a m3u8 file through MPMoviePlayerController .
I am using the service of [encoding.com](http://www.encoding.com/) to encode the stream from mp4's to m3u8 files
When we switch to an audio only stream we get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8Nfl.png) image (The quicktime logo).
But sometimes we get audio only data but the screen for the MPMoviePlayerController becomes blank (where the quicktime logo should be)

Could there be an issue with the encoding or is it something to do with the MPMoviePlayer?
If it is a MPMoviePlayer issue is there any way we could work around it ?

I have already tried to set the background image of the MPMoviePlayer view ..

Answer (score 2):

I am currently working with a pure .m3U8 file stream and it works just fine. So without seeing any code for your MPMoviePlayerController I would say it has something to do with your stream and/or the way it is encoded because I know for fact that MPMoviePlayer supports .m3U8 streams.

It is a good idea to upload to a server or service where you can just stream from a link. From there you can test if the stream itself is working on mobile by loading it in Safari.